# Why the same Lie algebra can be exponential mapped to different Lie groups?

Tags: differential-geometry, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In specific representations, it's understandable to see that matrices in different dimensions under the same exponential map get different Lie groups. But what if we do not choose any representations? Then how can the same Lie Algebra under the same map get different Lie groups?

Or is there any difference between the two mapping processes? If so, how to tell the difference between them without picking a representation?

*Sorry for any possible terminology abuse, I'm not majoring in mathematics. *

Comment: Do you have an example of your claim?

Comment: Yes, for example, SU(2) and SO(3) share the completely same Lie algebra. @Didier

Comment: If you look closer at examples, you should notice that it cannot be just *any* different Lie groups. In your example, there is a surjection $SU(2) \twoheadrightarrow SO(3)$. So a natural conjecture and refined question could be: Whenever this happens, is there a map from one of the Lie groups to the other, such that the one exponential is the other one composed with that map.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it's helpful, I'll think about it. It would be even nicer if you are willing to share more thoughts. @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: @Kisama This is because $SO(3)$ is the universal covering of $SU(2)$. In other words, $SO(3)$ is a quotient of $SU(2)$. What is true is that for each Lie algebra, there is a unique **simply connected** Lie group such that it is its Lie algbera

Comment: The trick is that those are not the same exponential map! Each Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ has its own exponential map $\mathrm{exp}:\mathfrak{g}\to G$. If you are viewing the Lie algebra as a set of matrices, you have picked a representation and then the matrix exponential map for that representation happens to coincide with one of the possible Lie group exponential maps but which one depends on the representation (and not every Lie group will show up this way).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information, now I'm just wonderingring if we can tell the difference between the map to the simply connected group and the map to the others without picking a representation. @Didier

Comment: @Callum Thank you for the helpful comment. So how to tell the difference between those maps without picking a representation?

Comment: @Kisama well mathematically, we have distinguished between them by specifying the Lie groups. Strictly speaking to define a function you must specify its codomain in advance. So the distinction is embedded within the definition of $\exp$ in each case.

Comment: As a side note I think it is worth saying that the Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ are exactly the quotient groups that we get by quotienting the (unique) simply connected one $\tilde{G}$ by discrete subgroups of its centre $Z(\tilde{G})$. You should be able to see that the exponential map plays nicely with respect to these quotients.

Comment: @Callum, I think I get your point now, thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Kisama not at all. This is a common thing especially since many people studying Lie theory come from a Physics background and are used to describing functions in quite an ad hoc manner. This distinction is subtle and abstract. In a representation it becomes less so of course.